# Average CPU utilization oracle database

Tags: oracle, license

I'm interested in understanding how DBAs think about the balance between Oracle's strict licensing requirements and the growing compute capacity of today's machines.  Oracle's insistence that customers must license all physical cores on a box for Oracle EE if any of Oracle EE is installed on the box, seems to be, at first blush, at odds with the fact that with larger, more powerful machines, customers can do more (beyond just Oracle) on those boxes (e.g. with virtualization, etc.).

Ultimately, I'm interested in assessing how much license over provisioning typically occurs for most customers.  Here's an example: If I am a large customer running Oracle EE on a machine with two high frequency Intel Xeon E5-2670 (Sandy Bridge) Processors and 20 physical cores, would I typically be using 100% of those cores 100% of the time to run Oracle DBs (in which case there is no overprovisioning, since the whole box utilization is 100%) or would a more likely scenario be running 50% of those cores 50% of the time for Oracle DBs (in which case the whole box utilization is 25%, so I've effectively paid for 3x more licenses than i actually need.

Would appreciate any insights on the typical utilization rates that you see on the servers that run your Oracle DBs, and whether you think this notion of `overprovisioning` is a real issue that you would avoid if you could (say by buying DB capacity on-demand).

Comment: You'd usually do a sizing exercise and then buy hardware for 120% (say) of the estimated peak workload in N years time, then license appropriately. CPU cores can be disabled, if needs be. Also, it's best to evaluate whether you REALLY need EE - some EE features can be scripted (log shipping to standby, for example), thus saving a large amount of cash.

Comment: You will always have peaks and troughs. You will need to balance what is the worst that you can accept with what you would like to be able to do bearing in mind what you can afford. Over-provisioning may be expensive, but under-provisioning may be more so depending on your circumstances. Of you could just use PostgreSQL, MySQL or Firebird and not care about licencing? But, if you're going to stick with Oracle, the licencing cost is always going to be there, as is the risk of not being able to service your users.

Answer (score 2):

Start using your licenses in a smart way. Many customers buy EE licenses, only using SE features. Don't underestimate the power of SE. You can use SE with a max of 4 sockets and with modern CPU's that's a lot of power. SE1 has a max of 2 sockets. See [Database Licensing - Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/databaselicensing-070584.pdf)

Next to that, consider consolidating your smaller applications into 1 serious database, often leading to much better CPU and license utilization. For one customer I saved 800.000,-/year doing so.

The question about how to size for over provisioning is really a business question. How does the business get hurt when it can't process every request immediately? Some will lose a lot of money for lost sales, others can handle it.

Comment: Little correction. SE can be used with up to 4 sockets. SE1 is limited with 2.

Comment: yes, you are right, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the reasons why good Oracle DBA can save quite a lot of money with licenses. First instead of using many core CPUs look into [Intel "Oracle EE"](http://ark.intel.com/compare/75268,75792,64595) line of server CPUs.

Next - put ton of RAM which is way cheaper nowadays than Oracle licenses. Then you can use [Database Smart Flash Cache](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/memory005.htm). MLC SSDs for servers are not that expensive.

But of course there is huge price gap between Standard Edition One and Enterprise Edition if we are talking about single dual CPU server.